# Optimal NUnit integration in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, nunit, mstest

I am doing a demo, and want Nunit better integrated in Visual Studio.

1. Menu options to Create NUnit test project and test class with reference to the framework (Like Microsoft Test does)
2. Run/Debug "selected tests" and individual tests with debugging.  I don't get it to work with [TestCase]-attribute, seems to run all testcases for a test.
3. Run failed tests with debugging.
4. Other cool stuff.

(Visual Studio 2015 RC)
I see some plugins in the gallery, but I am not sure if they do 1-3, and if they work.

Answer (score 2):

Try [NUnit Test Adapter](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/6ab922d0-21c0-4f06-ab5f-4ecd1fe7175d) or [NUnit3 Test Adapter](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/0da0f6bd-9bb6-4ae3-87a8-537788622f2d) from the makers of NUnit, or [ReSharper](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) if you want test runners and more.

You can make you own Visual Studio project templates but I'd just use the basic class library and nuget to get nunit libraries

They won't give you everything but it can be start.

Comment: NUnit3 Testadaper did not install to my 2015 RC.  (When clicking the download).  WHat about TestDrive.NET

Comment: 1. raise the issue with them - not me, 2. Never used it - I use ReSharper - FTW!

Comment: Yup - you see them listed separately and can run each individually as I recall.